# How to override WP_DEBUG for Ajax responses?

Tags: ajax, wp-debug

It is highly recommended practice (that I completely agree with) to develop with `WP_DEBUG` enabled. However it is merely inconvenient to see not yet fixed warnings in pages, but in Ajax responses they ruin response completely.

I am just starting with Ajax in WP, is there some appropriate hook to suppress errors for Ajax responses only?

PS fix everything is not viable option at moment, because it is extremely extensive and complex environment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `wp-config.php`:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX )
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
else
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Didn't realize that `DOING_AJAX` is defined very early, right at start of `admin-ajax.php`